# Why would java won't recognize a character comparision when I try to compare a slash?

Tags: java, if-statement, character, interpreter

I'm trying to do a Java interpreter for a new language and for this I need to tokenize each one of the characters. I found [Jasic](https://github.com/munificent/jasic) that is an already developed interpreter developed in Java so I'm using it as a guide. For the tokenizer I'm trying to change the the `if` statement that define that a character is a comment. Here is the code:

```
public static List<Token> tokenize(String source) {
    List<Token> tokens = new ArrayList<Token>();
    int n=0;

    String token = "";
    TokenizeState state = TokenizeState.DEFAULT;

    // Many tokens are a single character, like operators and ().
    String charTokens = "\n=+-*/<>()";
    TokenType[] tokenTypes = { TokenType.LINE, TokenType.EQUALS,
        TokenType.OPERATOR, TokenType.OPERATOR, TokenType.OPERATOR,
        TokenType.OPERATOR, TokenType.OPERATOR, TokenType.OPERATOR,
        TokenType.LEFT_PAREN, TokenType.RIGHT_PAREN
    };

    // Scan through the code one character at a time, building up the list
    // of tokens.
    for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
        char c = source.charAt(i);
        switch (state) {
        case DEFAULT:
            if (charTokens.indexOf(c) != -1) {
                tokens.add(new Token(Character.toString(c),
                    tokenTypes[charTokens.indexOf(c)]));
            } else if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                token += c;
                state = TokenizeState.WORD;
            } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                token += c;
                state = TokenizeState.NUMBER;
            } else if (c == '"') {
                state = TokenizeState.STRING;
            } else if (c == '/'){ // This comparision won't work
                state = TokenizeState.COMMENT;
            }
            /* This is how is handled by Jasic
               that uses a single quote for comments
            else if (c == '\'') {
                state = TokenizeState.COMMENT;
            }*/
            break;

        case WORD:
        // Here is more code, but not relevant for this question
}
```

I already tried even comparing the hashcode of the character and the type, also I tried to use `Character.valueOf(c)` to get only the value and compare it, like this: `Character.valueOf(c) == '/'` but nothing worked.

I've searched for answers but everything is about backslashes. So, my question is, do you know why it isn't working? or what I'm doing wrong that the `if` statement isn't accepting the comparision?

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: `c == '/'` is not even close to the same thing as `c == '\''`.  The commented out code looks for a single quote.  Is that what you intend for the newer code to do?

Comment: `/` is a division operator, so it was already handled by the `charTokens.indexOf(c) != -1` test, hence `c` can never be `/` in that `else if` statement. Besides, a `/` is **not** the start of a comment. `//` is.

Comment: @shmosel I used `System.out.print` to know that is reading the character but never enters the statement even when they are the same.

Comment: @JimGarrison The original code used single quote to start comments, what I'm trying to do is to change that so I can use slashes to comment.

Comment: @Andreas That looks like an answer...

Comment: @Andreas that was what I needed to know, so the slash is entering in the first `if else`, also I know that comment don't start with a single slash, but there are different type of comments (// and  /*) and I will handle it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/` is a division operator, according to the `charTokens` and `tokenTypes` variables.

This means that it was already handled by the `charTokens.indexOf(c) != -1` test, hence `c` can never be `/` in that `else if` statement.

Besides, a `/` is not the start of a comment. `//` is.